# Android view.animate() just jumps to final position instead of animating

Tags: android

I have a basic test project to isolate this problem. its just a blank Activity, a FrameLayout with a text view in the middle

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
        android:background="#88f"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
```

and in my activity I do this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    textView1.setOnClickListener {
        it.animate().rotationBy(45f).setDuration(2000).start()
    }
}
```

}

but instead of the view slowly rotating to the 45 portion, it just jumps to the final position without actually animating.

This used to work like a charm anywhere... but now all of a sudden it doesn't work.

here's my build.gradle incase its a library version thing

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.siavashb.testapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-

rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had animations disabled on my emulator. The reason this option exists is cuz animations sometimes cause problems for UI tests, which was the case for us. I disabled animations on my emulator a bout a year ago and totally forgot about it

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code as is; on api21 tablet, api24 and api29 phones and it worked like a charm. Also changed compile sdk to 29 and compiled with / without java 1.8, tried by using androidX artifacts, changed kotlin plugin version to 1.0 (current 1.3) nothing changed, it works on every combination, slowly rotates.
 Below is my Android Studio version and manifest file. Maybe you can try to invalidate your test project's cache and restart or cleanup your gradle directory as well. Hope it helps.

Android Studio:

> Android Studio 3.5.3 Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548, built on
>   November 15, 2019 JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 amd64 JVM:
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Linux 4.15.0-76-generic

My Gradle Version:

> gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

Manifest.xml

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.siavashb.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
//    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
//    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
//    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: No, it does the same thing no matter what the animation type is, rotation, translation, alpha, etc.

Comment: @Siavash, I edited my answer, please have a look. Maybe gives some clue.